# Software Design: EEPROM Object model

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a product that stores non-volatile values in an EEPROM during the production process. I currently model the EEPROM as a struct so I can easily Marshal to/from a buffer.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class EEPROM
{
    public const ushort MEMORY_VERSION = 0x01;
    ushort memoryVersion;
    byte value1 = 0;
    byte value2 = 0;
    public EEPROM() : this(MEMORY_VERSION) { }

    protected EEPROM(ushort memoryVersion) { this.memoryVersion = memoryVersion; }
}
```

Some time after these units have been fielded, I may need to add a new EEPROM setting. I need to come up with a way to handle in-field updates to the EEPROM. Our upgrade procedure wouldn't support an external application well, so I need to handle the upgrade in system.

My first thought was to add a virtual Upgrade method.

```
public virtual void Update() {}
```

and then inherit the out-dated EEPROM structure in a new one

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class EEPROM_V2 : EEPROM
{
    public new const ushort MEMORY_VERSION = 0x02;
    byte value3 = 0;

    public EEPROM_V2() : base(MEMORY_VERSION) { }
    protected TestEeprom(ushort memoryVersion) : base(MEMORY_VERSION) { }

    public override void Upgrade() { base.Upgrade(); value3 = 0; }
}
```

But this would force clients of EEPROM to change to EEPROM_V2. I have to be overthinking this. If I simply append new values, I could easily end up with a nasty if statement chain.

```
if( memoryVersion == X) { do this }
if( memoryVersion == Y) { do this }
etc...
```

Comment: What does _"this would force clients of EEPROM to change to EEPROM_V2"_ mean and why do you think so? If you mean someone has the code `EEPROM foo = YourCode.GetEEPROM()`, that'll just keep on working fine. The only thing is that they can then only access base members, not V2 members.

Comment: Sorry, poor wording. It would be access to child object members. Although I suppose you could argue that the issue would then lie with the client code.

Comment: EEPROM data is stored by two parameters, Address & Data.  Why not just have a function that takes the Address and the Data regardless of what the Address allocation is?  This way you don't need to add anything else for future allocations.

Comment: Definitely a KISS solution, would require maintaining a record of addresses and data sizes. Worth some thought, thanks.